# Algorithm to count the number of pairs whose sum exists in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Given an array of N integers. How can i count the number of pairs whose sum exists in the array?

E.g. `int a[] = {1, 3, 4, 6, 7}`. Here there are three such pairs: (1 + 3) = 4, (3 + 4) = 7, (1+6) = 7.

There are no duplicate numbers in the given array and the array is not sorted.Also the array can be changed,its not necessary to maintain the array.

I have tried the following two codes but I want to reduce complexity of my code to less than O(n^2).

Try 1:(Complexity is O(n^3))

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
main(){
    int i,input,j,n,ans=0,sum;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> vec;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>input;
        vec.push_back(input);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            sum=vec[i]+vec[j];
            if(find(vec.begin(),vec.end(),sum)!= vec.end()){
                ans++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<ans;
}
```

Comment: you inspect all pairs, if their sum is in the array you increment a counter

Comment: show what you tried and how it fails. SO is not a code writing service

Comment: I have added my code and also updated the question as there will be three pairs for given array

Comment: stackoverflow.com is not a web site where you can find someone else to write the code for some other online test site that you're taking.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This is not a program which is asked in some online test.I am preparing for placements and I have faced this question and was getting the issue.There is no such contest going on.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You can find a link to the question [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dailyhunt-interview-experience-set-1-campus/)

Comment: Same thing. The point of that is for you to figure it out yourself, and not find someone else who knows the answers. Because unless whoever you find will also go to your "placements" with you, that won't accomplish anything. And the chances of you getting an identical question yourself are infinitesimally small. You're wasting your time.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have tried the question myself and got to an answer and this is not about getting the same question in placements.I want to know whether I am missing something or not.Can I reduce the complexity from O(n^2) or not is my question

Comment: Does your second  algorithm count both  `(3 + 4)` and `(1+6)` for 7?

Comment: Not sure why down&close votes. I find the question useful and perfectly within scope. OP has shown an effort to solve it on his own and has specific issues why it's not good enough, seeking advise.

Comment: Your second approach will not find cases where two distinct pairs add to the same value.  In your example, `3+4 = 7` and `1+6 = 7` will only count one pair, not two.  So, yeah, it's faster, but doesn't produce the required result.

Comment: @amit As I noticed, algorithmic questions with the first tag of popular language (C#, Java, JS)  often cause a lot of DV/CVs

Comment: Also, your problem is under-specified.   Is the vector sorted?   Are elements unique or duplicated?    Can the vector be changed, or must it be left unchanged?

Comment: @Peter i have specified more details regarding the things you have mentioned

Comment: @MBo Yes my 2nd code does not count both `(3+4) and (1+6)`

Comment: @MBo i have updated my 2nd code and now it works for the given input.

Comment: @Tarun Talreja Does this code give result `k*(k-1)` for natural sequence with `n=2*k` like `1,2,3...14=>42` ?

Comment: @MBo Yes this code gives result `42` for the array `1,2,3,...,14`

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get complexity below O(n²), even just enumerating the possible pairs is O(n²)...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help reduce the complexity, but I think it's simpler this way since you don't declare any variables in the function that you're using, saving the memory and time:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
bool checkForEveryElement(vector<int> vec,int sum)
{
    for( int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j<vec.size(); j++)
           if(vec[i] + vec[j] == sum)
             return 1;
    }    
    return 0;
}
void main(){
    int i,input,j,n,ans=0,sum;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> vec;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>input;
        vec.push_back(input);
    }
    sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(checkForEveryElement(vec,vec[i])){
            ans++;
        }
    cout<<ans;
}
```

Comment: You have increased the complexity of my code to O(n^3) . I want to reduce it not increase.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through using arrays or vectors so you can iterate as a bubble-sort algorithm; So the first loop (outer) begins from element 0 until the end and the inner begins form the outer loop index + 1 to avoid summing the element with itself. And each inner loop we calculate the sum of element i + element i + 1.
Storing the sum in a temporary variable. Finally an inner most loop begins from i + 2 As long as i summed with j (i + 1) and the result begins from the third element:

```
int a[] = {1, 3, 4, 6, 7};

for(int i(0); i < 5; i++){
    for(int j(i + 1); j < 5; j++){
        int sum = a[i] + a[j];
        for(int k(j + 1); k < 5; k++){
            if (sum == a[k])
                std::cout << "(" << a[i] << ", " << a[j] << "): " << sum << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

*I wish this will help you in reducing the elapsed time.

Comment: You have done the same thing and increased the complexity of my code to O(n^3) . I want to reduce it .